# Facebook permissions changes killing project

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web, facebook-sdk-3.0

I have an web application that migrats with Facebook, issue is: The application is built to get users friends list to an object, And send a message to all these friends, I saw on **Facebook that they allow 250 users** to receive message at once, On this page : https://www.facebook.com/help/messages/sending under "How many people can I message at once", So I started to work on the project.

All around the web I wasn't able to find a solution to send message and kinda understand that it isn't possible, only trough Ruby under Facebook Chat API, but that doesn't seems to solve any real issue.

From there I tried to check out maybe I can upload a photo and tags these users, Also has limitations to 50 friends and they also have to approve applications before that, might be the solution, didn't find anyone that done it before so ofcourse didn't find good guides aswell, and it isn't a real solution.

**My question is**: because I'm so far into that project, I dont really have a way to go back (also sent documents to the project manager that expact this project), is there a way to send multipie request/feeds/tags/messages/ anything that can save this idea, anything will be helpful!, Thanks ahead!

*Take in note that project is built with **Javascript SDK**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to create a page for an event where you can add people and where those people can RSVP for the event? I have just the thing for you: https://www.facebook.com/help/events

Comment: Nailed it!, it's not perfect solution for the problem, but it's probably the best there is right now. 
I'm on it and it seems to be working just fine untill now!

Answer (score 2):

As I already explained to you on IRC, your concept is raising all the red flags for spamming.

It isn't possible to send multiple requests like this.

- **https://www.facebook.com/help/messages/sending**
  This restriction is for the Facebook UI, that is not the API. Use https://developers.facebook.com for research
- **[Facebook Chat API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/)**
  This is for *realtime* communication only. It shouldn't be used for broadcasts
- **Upload a photo and tags these users**
  This is also a misuse of the API. The documentation specifically states not to do this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/photos/

> Users should always have choice and control in how they use Facebook channels and products. Because of this, apps should never automatically tag a user or their friends in a photo. Please obtain express consent of the user on whose behalf you are doing the tagging, and also remember that users can tag friends even after the image is added to their profile.
>   
>   You're out of luck and you are trying methods that will bring your application negative user feedback and/or application removal. You need to drop/revise your concept and talk to your PM immediately, because what you are currently doing is not possible within the Facebook Developer Policies and Guidelines.

Comment: Hi, And thanks for the answer, I would like to add something that might be able to look at things in another way.
The application is not doing nothing without user permissions, The user himself simply sends to friends a website that he is building for he's own wedding, nothing to do with application spamming, and he sends it to he's own friends, like: "Hi dagan, see my website: http://whatever , and please approve your arrvial to the wedding", thats it.. and thats why I'm sure that there is a way, beucase it's not application but the user it self.. atleast hope so.